# What are Google AdSense Products Names?

Tags: jquery, json, adsense, adsense-api

I'm using the Google AdSense API. "https://developers.google.com/adsense/management/v1.4/reference/adclients" When I run these codes, a list of products for my AdSense account appears. But I want to know what "***productCode***" means.

[image: Adsense Info]

**What do they mean?**

AFC_HOST

AFC

AFS

**Example:**

```
What do they mean?
AFC_HOST = YouTube AdSense
AFC = Web AdSense
AFS = AdSense for search
```

```
{
 "kind": "adsense#adClients",
 "etag": "\"J_-wNXXXXXXXXXXXdXUxeLK8/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\"",
 "items": [
  {
   "id": "ca-host-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
   "kind": "adsense#adClient",
   "productCode": "AFC_HOST",
   "supportsReporting": true
  },
  {
   "id": "ca-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
   "kind": "adsense#adClient",
   "productCode": "AFC",
   "supportsReporting": true,
   "arcOptIn": true
  },
  {
   "id": "partner-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
   "kind": "adsense#adClient",
   "productCode": "AFS",
   "supportsReporting": true
  }
 ]
}
```

Comment: The product code will be ones definined as products in reporting dimension from looking at the docs. Check reporting section. Maybe also this [link](https://www.webnots.com/google-adsense-products/) may help

Comment: - Web (AFC)
- YouTube (AFC_HOST)
- Arama (AFS)
- Video (AFV)
- Alışveriş (AFSh)
- Oyunlar (AFG)
- AdMob (GMOB)